# Updating Helpbook bundle in OSX application

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am on MacOS Mojave (10.14), not iOS. Xcode 10, Objective-C.

I have an application with an already implemented Helpbook. Everything works fine.
Now i need to update the help book.

I recreated the helpbook bundle. Replaced the old one in Xcode with the new one (create folder references).
When i build the app and open the package contents, the new helpbook is included. Great. But the app shows the old one.

What have i done:

- Clean derived data with XCode closed
- Clean product/folder
- Logged out/in (assuming theres some kind of cache)
- Cleaned the helpbook cache and restarted (see script below)

Still the old help book.
What am i missing?

Helpbook cache cleaning script i use (credits: http://macergun.blogspot.com/2011/06/dealing-with-help-viewer-cache.html)

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
killall helpd
defaults write com.apple.helpindexer IndexAnchors YES
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, xcode 10, just upgraded to mojave. Every change I push results in no update or blank pages. Beginning to think this a bug